# Regex pattern issue

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
!date +10 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz)
```

this string could be also (notice the minus instead of the plus.:

```
!date -10 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz)
```

I need a regex pattern that will extract the numeric digits after the + (or -). There could be more than one digit.

I also need a pattern to extract the contents of the brackets ();

I've had a play around on regex pal. but couldn't get a working pattern.

Cheers.

Comment: What you have tried ?What should be your output?

Answer (score 3):

To pick out the number & bracket content, you could do:

```
String str = "date +10 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*[+|-](\\d+).*\\((.*)\\).*").matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should give you a match with the digits after the +/- and the contents of the parentheses in the first and second capturing group, respectively:

```
"!date\\s[+-](\\d+)\\s\\(([^)]*)\\)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex leads to 2 capturing groups with the contents you want

```
"!date\\s[+-](\\d+)\\s\\((\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}'T'\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}z)\\)"
```